90's film about mother and daughter... European, (French?)
In the 90's I watched a film in France, (may have been a French Film certainly was NOT an English Language film), that told the story of a mother and daughter choosing to spend the night with each other's partners. 
The mother had a very raunchy encounter with her daughter's boyfriend whilst the expected tryst between the daughter and her mothers boyfriend never took place. The actress who played the mother was a relatively well known brunette actress of the time- she was on billboards I seem to remember. 
The truth is this film may have been made for TV, and it might not be the most accurate synopsis of the movie. 
I have searched for this movie for years and to no avail so any pointers would be well received! 

Could the actress be Juliette Binoche?
